Ansible: How to merge two different sized lists of dicts
a task in ansible 2.10.8:
I would like to merge two different lists of dicts to get one complemented with missing items, but not add a dict to the first list.
List of dicts one:
user_users:
  - username: 'foo'
    primarygid: 42
  - username: 'bar'

List of dicts two:
user_users_skel:
  - username: foo
    uid: 600
    primarygid: 600
    shell: '/bin/bash'
    ssh_login: false
  - username: bar
    uid: 602
    primarygid: 602
    shell: '/bin/bash'
    ssh_login: true
  - username: blupp
    uid: 1000
    primarygid: 1000
    shell: '/bin/bash'
    ssh_login: true
    default_groups: 'admin'
    initial_password_hash: '$2349887rhfewklrjn'

Expected Output (also a list of dicts):
  - username: foo
    uid: 600
    primarygid: 42
    shell: '/bin/bash'
    ssh_login: false
  - username: bar
    uid: 602
    primarygid: 602
    shell: '/bin/bash'
    ssh_login: true

I used different approaches, like
    - set_fact:
        eff_users: "{{ user_users | ansible.builtin.combine(user_users_skel) }}"
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: eff_users

with bogus output.

These lists of dicts are generated by me to build -indeed- a user management-role. The mentioned ansible module will be used in a second step with the correct output list of dicts. But it can't help to create it.


Merge the lists

  users_all: "{{ [user_users, user_users_skel] |
                 community.general.lists_mergeby('username') }}"

gives
  users_all:
  - primarygid: 602
    shell: /bin/bash
    ssh_login: true
    uid: 602
    username: bar
  - default_groups: admin
    initial_password_hash: $2349887rhfewklrjn
    primarygid: 1000
    shell: /bin/bash
    ssh_login: true
    uid: 1000
    username: blupp
  - primarygid: 600
    shell: /bin/bash
    ssh_login: false
    uid: 600
    username: foo


Get the list usernames

  usernames: "{{ user_users | map(attribute='username') }}"

gives
  usernames:
  - foo
  - bar


Select username in the list

  eff_users: "{{ users_all | selectattr('username', 'in', usernames) }}"

gives what you want
  eff_users:
  - primarygid: 602
    shell: /bin/bash
    ssh_login: true
    uid: 602
    username: bar
  - primarygid: 600
    shell: /bin/bash
    ssh_login: false
    uid: 600
    username: foo



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: all

  vars:

    user_users:
      - username: foo
        primarygid: 42
      - username: bar

    user_users_skel:
      - username: foo
        uid: 600
        primarygid: 600
        shell: /bin/bash
        ssh_login: false
      - username: bar
        uid: 602
        primarygid: 602
        shell: /bin/bash
        ssh_login: true
      - username: blupp
        uid: 1000
        primarygid: 1000
        shell: /bin/bash
        ssh_login: true
        default_groups: admin
        initial_password_hash: $2349887rhfewklrjn

    users_all: "{{ [user_users, user_users_skel] |
                   community.general.lists_mergeby('username') }}"
    usernames: "{{ user_users | map(attribute='username') }}"
    eff_users: "{{ users_all | selectattr('username', 'in', usernames) }}"
        
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: users_all
    - debug:
        var: usernames
    - debug:
        var: eff_users



Update: user_users  and user_users_skel in  users_all: "{{ [user_users, user_users_skel] | needs exchanged. Than it works like expected.
